# How to spread a python array

Tags: python

In JS I can do this

```
const a = [1,2,3,4]
const b = [10, ...a]
console.log(b) // [10,1,2,3,4]
```

Is there a similar way in python?

Comment: Just add them: `b = [10] + a`

Answer (score 180, accepted):

As Alexander points out in the comments, list addition is concatenation.

```
a = [1,2,3,4]
b = [10] + a  # N.B. that this is NOT `10 + a`
# [10, 1, 2, 3, 4]
```

You can also use `list.extend`

```
a = [1,2,3,4]
b = [10]
b.extend(a)
# b is [10, 1, 2, 3, 4]
```

and newer versions of Python allow you to (ab)use the splat (`*`) operator.

```
b = [10, *a]
# [10, 1, 2, 3, 4]
```

---

Your choice may reflect a need to mutate (or not mutate) an existing list, though.

```
a = [1,2,3,4]
b = [10]
DONTCHANGE = b

b = b + a  # (or b += a)
# DONTCHANGE stays [10]
# b is assigned to the new list [10, 1, 2, 3, 4]

b = [*b, *a]
# same as above

b.extend(a)
# DONTCHANGE is now [10, 1, 2, 3, 4]! Uh oh!
# b is too, of course...
```

Comment: is there a differencde between extend and []+[]

Comment: @TylerCowan The former modifies one list and returns `None`, the latter returns a new list containing all the elements. Otherwise no.

Comment: the last example only works on python3

Comment: the [] + [] takes more memory than .extend() because its a 2-step process

Comment: @Mincho that's probably true, but maybe not for the reason you're thinking. Certainly not because it's a 2-step process. after `c = a + b` you have three lists, `a`, `b`, and `c`. Each one has to be held in memory until it falls out of scope (unless you `del a; del b`). After `a.extend(b)` you have only two lists -- `a` and `b`. That said: the biggest difference is still that `list.extend` mutates the existing list while `list.__add__` produces a new one.

Answer (score 11):

The question does not make clear what exactly you want to achieve.

To replicate that operation you can use the Python list `extend` method, which appends items from the list you pass as an argument:

```
>>> list_one = [1,2,3]
>>> list_two = [4,5,6]
>>> list_one.extend(list_two)
>>> list_one
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
```

If what you need is to extend a list at a specific insertion point you can use list slicing:

```
>>> l = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
>>> l[2:2] = ['a', 'b', 'c']
>>> l
[1, 2, 'a', 'b', 'c', 3, 4, 5]
```

Answer (score 6):

Python's list object has the `.extend` function.

You can use it like this:

```
    a = [1, 2, 3, 4]
    b = [10]
    b.extend(a)
    print(b)
```

Comment: bah, I missed one ;) May be worth pointing out specifically that `list.extend` returns `None`, so not to use `b = b.extend(a)`. That's a common mistake from beginner Python users.

Comment: @AdamSmith It's also worth knowing which types are mutable/immutable. In python, lists are mutable.

Comment: Good point, and one that was lacking from my own answer. Thanks!