# Use of *args in manim ReplacementTransform animation

Tags: list-comprehension, args, manim

I have a question regarding this piece of code, which transforms the elements of TexMobject (for example, element 2 is transformed to 8, 3 is transformed to 9 and so on):

```
changes = [
          [(2,4,3), (8,11,9)],
          [(0,0), (7,10)]
          ]    

for pre_ind, post_ind in changes:
        self.play(
            *[
                ReplacementTransform(formula[i].copy(), formula[j])
                for i,j in zip(pre_ind, post_ind)
            ]
        )
        self.wait()
    self.wait()
```

I see that there is a list comprehension used to generate indices pairs, but I don't understand why is there an  args asterisk (*) before the square brackets in `self.play()`? What is the purpose of using *args notation in this case, if list comprehension works without it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to understand a couple of concepts before:

1. List comprehension only works on lists, tuples, dictionaries and sets.
2. `self.play()` refers to `Scene.play()`, because we know that `self` refers to the class being defined.
3. ALL METHODS have the following form: `class.method(*args,**kwargs)`, or

```
class.method(*args_1, *args_2, *args_3, ..., *args_n,**kwargs_1, **kwargs_2, ..., **kwargs_m)
```

Where `args` is a LIST/TUPLA and `kwargs` is a dictionary. In this case, `Scene.play` is used like this:

```py
Scene.play(Animation1(...), Animation2(...), ..., **kwargs)
# Example:
Scene.play(Write(mob1), Write(mob2), run_time=4)

# But, this is the same as:
Scene.play(*[Write(mob1), Write(mob2)], run_time=4)

# Or better:
Scene.play(*[Write(mobs) for mobs in [mob1,mob2]], run_time=4)
```

I suppose (you didn't make it very clear) that you are referring to why you can't do something like:

```
Scene.play([ReplacementTransform(...) for _ in ...])
```

or

```
Scene.play(ReplacementTransform(...) for _ in ...)
```

Intuitively we can understand that this is a syntax error, because the Python interpreter will not be able to understand the parameters that are being given, remember that this is NOT the way to use a method.

The operator `*` is called "spread operator", what it does is "take out" all the elements that are in a list. More information [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48451228/how-to-spread-a-python-array).