# Is there a rest operator in python?

Tags: javascript, python, arrays

I am familiar with the spread/rest syntax in JavaScript:

```js
// spread syntax
const foo = [1, 2];
const bar = [3, 4];

console.log([...foo, ...bar]); // [1, 2, 3, 4]

// rest syntax
function baz(...nums) {
  console.log(nums);
}

baz(1, 2, 3); // [1, 2 ,3]
```

I know how to concatenate arrays.

```py
foo = [1, 2, 3]
bar = [*foo, 4, 5]
print(bar) # [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
```

Is there a way to use the **Rest Syntax** in python?

PS: Look at the second JS example.

Comment: In JavaScript, `...` is not an "operator"; it's a syntax construct but it's not part of the expression grammar. In Python, you can use the `+` operator to do concatenation things on arrays.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to spread a python array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48451228/how-to-spread-a-python-array), or [How do I concatenate two lists in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1720421/how-do-i-concatenate-two-lists-in-python)

Comment: You can use `*`. So, `[1, 2, *bar, 5, 6]` or for your example, `[*foo, *bar]`

Comment: What about the rest syntax? As shown in the second example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply combine them, this has the same effect as the JS spread operator.

```
listOne = [1, 2, 3]
listTwo = [9, 10, 11]

joinedList = listOne + listTwo
// [1, 2, 3, 9, 10, 11]
```

As pointed out in the comments, the direct equivalent would be to use the `*` operator.

```
joinedList = [*listOne, *listTwo]
```

Comment: This is a clear duplicate with similar but more complete answers

Comment: Apologies, I didnt search I just answered, my bad.

Comment: The direct equivalent in Python would be `*`, so `[*listOne, *listTwo]`

Comment: Very good point, edited to reflect